# How to get a clearer picture from FBO?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, fbo

I'm new to both android and opengl es, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.
First of all, I've create a GLSurfaceView and set its width to 300 and height to 500. Then I create an FBO and attach it to texture. Finally, I draw the texture to the screen.
So, here is my question: If I want to get a clearer picture, like 1000*800. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I create an FBO and attach it to texture

1. FBO is a render target which means you can't attach it to a texture. However, you can draw a object with the texture to a FBO

> I want to get a clearer picture, like 1000*800

2. Thus, whatever the original picture size is, the maximum size of a clear picture is depending on your FBO size set by

**glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_RGBA8, width, height);
using RTT(render-to-texture)**

You can export a texture from a FBO using RTT (render-to-texture)

RTT is a way to use your render target as a texture.

e.g)

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture[texture_id].texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[texture_id].texture_id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture_width, texture_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[texture_id].texture_id, 0);
```